# FileNotFoundException with properties file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties

I'm trying to read some props from `backupData.properties`. It locates in `WEB-INF/classes/`. This is how I do:

```
public class Configures {

    private static final String INPUT_FILE = "WEB-INF//classes//backupData.properties"; 


    public static String getMail() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            //load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE));

            //get the property value
            return prop.getProperty("mail");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What `INPUT_FILE` should contain? I was trying to put it in `src`, like `src//backupData.properties`, but it throws `FileNotFoundException`. I googled that file should locate in `CLASSPATH`(in `WEB-INF/classes` as I understood). What is wrong?

*PS. I'm using Spring.*

Comment: do you check with absolute path ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Spring. If you are deploying a web application, everything in `WEB-INF/classes` will appear starting at the root of the classpath.

You can get it the `InputStream` to that resource with

```
InputStream in = Configures.class.getResourceAsStream("/backupData.properties");
prop.load(in);
```

Since a web application is not always extracted from its `.war` file, the actual properties file might only exist as a zip entry. As such, you can't (and shouldn't) retrieve it with `FileInputStream`.

[Here's the javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I don't think you want the slash in the name.

Comment: @jalynn2 Why don't you think so?

Comment: because it is in the root of the classpath?

Comment: @jalynn2 For that specific reason, it needs to have the leading `/`. Otherwise, it would be resolved relative the  package that `Configures` is in.

Comment: @Tony You're welcome. Take a look at the javadoc I've linked and try to familiarize yourself with the classpath. Web apps are a little different than standalone apps in that regard.

Comment: @Sortirios- I didn't read your answer carefully enough. I usually use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`

Comment: @jalynn2 Ah, one or the other. You have to be careful in this case which `ClassLoader` you use (if you are using the instance method).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SPRING , I suggest you "CAN" use this as part of your Bean definition:

```
<property name="template" value="classpath:/backupData.properties">
```

or

```
Resource template = ctx.getResource("classpath:/backupData.properties");
```

or the plain old as suggested by `@Sotirios Delimanolis`